# I'm getting a Routing error saying it can't find the font

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am getting a routing error saying a font doesn't exist, but I can see the font in my assets folder.

error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/fonts/some-font.ttf"):
```

I added the font to the folder: app/assets/fonts/some-font.ttf

I'm using rails 4.2

Comment: Maybe you should try restart server

Comment: I have restarted it many times already, no change.

Comment: Here my config: app/assets/styles../fonts.scss
https://box.everhelper.me/attachment/382447/lERGrvrTxMYwd6a4tYeGg2Lhn4gcaWr6/446627-wfe5nkpMGhyaiFZh/screen.png

Hope it can help you :)